# Updating visual studio 2019 professional Rc to specific version rather than latest version

Tags: visual-studio, version, updates

I want to update visual studio 2019 professional Rc 16.7 to 16.8.3 to run asp.net core 5.

Every time I try to update using visual studio installer, I get the latest version and when I download the installer from this link [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/history](https://microsoft.com), I always update the latest version as well.

** So please help me to update the specific version in some ways. Thank in advance for my supporters**

welcome all solutions provided by enthusiastic members.